# .slideToggle on .click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, slidetoggle, toggleclass

I'm building a Tumblr site and I want that when a user clicks on the tags span, it should display the tags. It was working properly until today, and now when you click on, it comes back immediately. I can't figure out what is wrong.

HTML

```
<span class="tags-link">Tags</span>
{block:HasTags}
    <ul class="tags tags-close">
    {block:Tags}
        <li>
            <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
        </li>
    {/block:Tags}
    </ul>
 {/block:HasTags}
```

CSS

```
.tags{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}

.tags-open{
    display: block;
}

.tags li{   
    font-size: 14px;
}

.tags li a{
    color: #9CA8B3;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.tags-close{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tags-link").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".tags").slideToggle(500, function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("tags-open");
            $(".tags li").css("display","inline-block");
            //end animation
        });
    }); // end tags
}); // end ready
```

Comment: If it worked, and now doesn't the first thing to investigate is what changed. If you think the answer is 'nothing' you are probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try using .toggle() instead, i believe through JQuery UI you can achieve the slide effect.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    var tags = $(this).next('.tags');
    tags.toggle('slide', {direction:'up'},500);
    $(this).animate(500).toggleClass("tags-open"); //animate fades class changes
    $("li.tags").animate(500).css("display","inline-block");

});
```